# MongoDB Complex Query with Java

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

We have following structure in MongoDB documents.

```
{
"id":"1111",
"keys":[
{
"name":"Country",
"value":"USA"
},
{
"name":"City",
"value":"LongIsland"
},
{
"name":"State",
"value":"NewYork"
}
]
}
```

Now using Springframework Query object, I figured out a way to pull the details using below syntax

```
query.addCriteria(
        Criteria.where("keys.value").is(countryparam).
        andOperator(
                Criteria.where("keys.value").is(stateparam)
                )
        );
```

Two issue with this query model.

First issue is it is irrelevant if countryparam and stateparam are actually meant to match Country key name and State key name respectively. If just the values matches, the query returns the document. Means, if I have Country and City params, this just works if user passes Country and City values, even if they are swapped. So how can I exactly compare City to cityparam and State to Stateparam?

More complexity is if I have to extract the document basing on multiple key value pairs, I should be correspondingly able to match key name with respective value and query the document. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you looked at [elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#elemmatch-query)?

Comment: Thanks. I am seeing some light with following query, but struggling to fit it in with the Springboot Query code.

`db.getCollection('mycollection').find({"keys":{"name":"City", "value" : "CityParamValue"}, "keys":{"name":"Country", "value" : "CountryParamValue"}})`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15770086/mongodb-spring-data-criteria-all 
finally helped! I got the solution.